# Remove space between new line output

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to capture the output in one of the file using

```
cat <<EOF> /var/log/awsmetadata.log
    timestamp= $TIME, \
    region= $REGION, \
    instanceIp= $INSTANCE_IP, \
    availabilityZone= $INSTANCE_AZ, \
    instanceType= $INSTANCE_TYPE, \
EOF
```

Where the output created in the format of

```
cat /var/log/awsmeta.log
    timestamp= 2020-11-04 18:51:17,     region= us-west-2,     instanceIp= 1.2.3.4,     availabilityZone= us-west-2a,
```

How can i eliminate the wide spaces between each output line?

Comment: Do you want to start with a tab?

Comment: It doesn't matter as far as output is in the right format, This output basically goes to ELK logs, for that reason I am looking to eliminate the spaces between each output you see. Any other preferred way works too. @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want redundant whitespaces simply do not add them:

```
$ cat <<EOF> /var/log/awsmetadata.log
> timestamp= $TIME, \
> region= $REGION, \
> instanceIp= $INSTANCE_IP, \
> availabilityZone= $INSTANCE_AZ, \
> instanceType= $INSTANCE_TYPE
> EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use `sed` or `tr` instead of `cat` for this sort of thing:

```
tr -s ' ' <<EOF > /var/log/awsmetadata.log
    timestamp= $TIME, \
    region= $REGION, \
    instanceIp= $INSTANCE_IP, \
    availabilityZone= $INSTANCE_AZ, \
    instanceType= $INSTANCE_TYPE,
EOF
```

But it seems cleaner to not escape the newlines at all and do something like:

```
{ tr -d \\n <<-EOF; echo; } > /var/log/awsmetadata.log
        timestamp= $TIME,
        region= $REGION,
        instanceIp= $INSTANCE_IP,
        availabilityZone= $INSTANCE_AZ,
        instanceType= $INSTANCE_TYPE,
EOF
```

(That solution uses the `<<-` form of the heredoc which redacts hardtabbed indenation.  It will not remove leading spaces.)

OTOH, it seems weird to be using a here doc when you're just wanting to generate one line of output.  Why not just use `echo`?

Comment: This is one of the best ways to generate using echo, appreciated for the suggestion.